# JScrollPane, overlapping panels inside

Tags: java, jscrollpane, overlap

I've currently got a JScrollPane in which I am placing panels inside of.
For some reason the panels are not being placed side by side, rather they are overlapping on each other in the top left hand corner of the JScrollPane.

```
public class UI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ArrayList<LibraryImagePanel> libPanels;

    /**
     * Creates new form UI
     */
    public UI() {
        initComponents();
        this.setResizable(false);

        scrollpane_library.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollpane_library.add(new LibraryImagePanel());

        libPanels = new ArrayList<>();
    }

...

}


class LibraryImagePanel extends JPanel {
    /**
     * CTOR
     */
    LibraryImagePanel(){
        this.setSize(256, 256);
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param g Graphics
     */    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(0,0,20,20);
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a single parent `JPanel` inside the `JScrollPane`.
2. Set its `LayoutManager` as Horizontal or Flow layout (or whichever you like).
3. Add all `LibraryImagePanel`'s to this parent panel.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
You also need to call validate() on a panel when you change component hierarchy (add or remove elements) inside it.
Just call

```
scrollPanel.validate();
```

after adding each panel to it.

Comment: Hmm it still appears to be overlapping.
Here's my new UI constructor:

http://pastie.org/private/uwqkrg8pjukcnrz1r8ung

And yes, I added the LibraryImagePanels to the scrollPanel, not the scrollpane_library object.

Comment: You haven't added anything to the scrollPanel... o.O

Comment: I was showing the code for my scrollpane to show that it has a JPanel with a FlowLayout.

scrollPanel does have panels added to it, I know this because it's working, however the panels are overlapping.

http://pastie.org/private/llgju0vafgacckqiknwwa

Was there something wrong with the way I set the layout?

Comment: I can't be sure as I haven't seen the code, but I'd suggest you to make sure you are adding the panels to scrollPanel and not scrollpane_library

Comment: Yup, new pastie on previous comment. Line 109.

Comment: Check the edit. It seemed to large to fit in this comment.. :D

Comment: All right now that I do validate(), the panels appear to be being added side by side finally, but the panels are like 4x4 pixels in size! They should be at least 256x256?

http://pastie.org/private/bodhe38mcxediq6ode63jw

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:
http://i.imgur.com/nHqSBjI.png

Comment: That may be because you have called `setSize`. Use preferred size in stead. If your previous problem has been solved, accept some answer or post your own so other people know that the issue has been resolved, and their time is saved.

Comment: It's possible the answer may be causing this problem though.
Also using scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(scrollpane_library.getSize()); as opposed to using scrollPanel.setSize(scrollpane_library.getSize()); makes it so I can't even see my panels anymore. Nothing shows up. They show up with .setSize() but still in little 8x8 images with the line I was drawing.

Comment: How about `scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(256, 256);`?

Comment: Well technically it's scrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(256, 256)); but doing this nothing shows up.
Not sure what the point of that is though because we need the parent panel to be as big as the scroll pane.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample seems to be missing some important parts (where do you create `scrollpane_library`?) Regardless, if `scrollpane_library` is a `JScrollPane`, try passing your panel to `JScrollPane`'s constructor. You can also set the scrollbar policy through the constructor.

You can have a single component in a JScrollPane. If you have more than one panel that you want to scroll, then create another JPanel that contains those panels (let's call this `bigPanel`), then use `bigPanel` in the JScrollPane.